# scrollTop not working on example using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me why `scrollTop` is not working. Actually I want to scroll the focus on that while where I give command to prepend the text.
Actually The focus goes to top of text prepend text. I need the focus should move remain still.

here is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/d9584/21/

when I prepend the text focus goes to top of line.

```
$("#contend").scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        alert("ssss");
        $("#pre").prepend(" Distinguished service of a high degree to Australia or to humanity at largefjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda  sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda  sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda  sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf sdfjsflsj sdflkjsdlfjsldfj sdfsjdflsf adasda");
        alert($("#pre")[0].scrollHeight)
        $("#pre").prependTo("#contend");
        document.getElementById("content").scrollTop = $("#pre")[0].scrollHeight
    }
});

$("#contend").scroll(function () {
    if ($('#contend').scrollTop() >= $('#contend')[0].scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) {
        $("#pre").html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why applying .scroll on same ID two times?

Comment: one is to get top , other to get bottom of page event

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$(this).scrollTop()
```

would never be 0

try to change

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
```

to

```
if( $(this).scrollTop() < 1) {
```